# How to use text-transform in middle of a paragraph or div?

Tags: html, css

I am using text-transform in the root to capitalize in my css file. Is there a way to text-transform lower-case a part of text in the middle of a div or p?

Comment: You can wrap that part of the text in a span tag and give it css prop for lower-case. Or you can create a class for it.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the example with word "dolor".

```css
:root {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.lowercase {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span class="lowercase">dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div>Lorem ipsum <span class="lowercase">dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .lower-case {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>HELLO <span class="lower-case">WORLD</span> TEST</div>
  </body>
</html>
```